# Is this true $y=x^2 \Rightarrow x=y^{1/2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I am trying to solve $y=x^2$ for $x$ then does $x=y^{1/2}$ by raising the two sides to $1/2$?

Comment: Sure, that is one of the law of indices

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an even root you would write $y=x^2\implies x=\pm y^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

X could also be $x = -y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ since $(-1)^{2}=1$. Where are you working anyways? The reals the complex plane?